# How do I add hyphens to specific cells in a Pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame where dates have not all been filled in correctly. I need to clean some dates so that Pandas.to_datetime is able to parse the information.

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas 
datums = {'Naam': ['Alfa', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon', 'Zieta', 'Icta', 'Thieta', 
               'Jotta', 'Kappa', 'Lambda', 'Mu', 'Nu'],
   'Datum': ['2842001', '0952002', '1312003', '1112004', '1122005', '3122006', '2232007', '3112008', 
             '1212009', '9102010', '3292011', '3302012', '4412013']}

df = pandas.DataFrame(datums, columns=['Naam', 'Datum'])
```

The first row with Naam Alfa is clearly a typo of 28042001.

I'm able to filter the correct rows with str.contains('^[1|2][4-9[4-9]....$'

When I try to use str.replace to I'm not able to keep the existing data whilst only adding the hyphens in the correct place.

This is what I tried:

```
df.Datum.str.replace(r'^[1|2][4-9][4-9]....$', '\d\d-\d-\d\d\d\d', regex=True)
```

This returns an error of bad escape \d at position 0

I also tried:

```
df.Datum.str.replace(r'^[1|2][4-9][4-9]....$', '{}-{}-{}'.format(df['Datum'][:2], df['Datum'][2:3], df['Datum'][3:]), regex=True)
```

This runs but doesn't change anything.

I've tried to play around with the code without any luck. A pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Datum'] = df['Datum'].str.replace(r'^(\d{2})(\d)(\d+)$', r'\1-\2-\3')
```

The `^(\d{2})(\d)(\d+)$` pattern will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1 (its value can be referenced to from the replacement pattern with the `\1` replacement backreference): two digits
- `(\d)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one digit
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 (`\3`): any 0 or more digits
- `$` - till end of string.

Comment: Thank you. This works! To make sure that I don't end up with any digit over 2 I used:
df['Datum'] = df.Datum.str.replace(r'^([1|2][4-9])([4-9])(\d{4})$', r'\1-\2-\3')

Comment: @YuriTchong Then please fix the regex and use `r'^([12][4-9])([4-9])(\d{4})$'`

Comment: @ Wiktor, I did. Thank you. I'm afraid it'll be a while before regex is second nature to me. I also updated the first group to [12].